# What is the difference between variable, parameter and field in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am a newbie to *JasperReports*, have been working on some small samples. It seems "Fields", "Parameters" and "Variables" are very commonly used to demonstrate dynamic data and looks much alike. So can I ask what's their difference specifically in *JasperReports*?

I guess variable is something defined within a Jasper report and can dynamically change. Parameter is something taking from external source (Java..etc), field is for entities (database schema, class entity), but I don't think my understand is all right.

Comment: As an addition to other answers, here the official [**JasperReports Library - Tutorial**](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial) where, among other, there is related sections discussing [*Variables*](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial#Variables), [*Parameters*](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial#Parameters) and [*Fields*](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial#Fields).

Comment: Also might be useful to read *"Chapter 6: Fields, Parameters and Variables"* of the **"iReport Ultimate Guide"** available for download [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation) (to download you must register).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From my personal experience with `JasperReports` i can deduce that you will be using Parameters and Fields the most. Parameters and fields are memory locations or values which you can populate from your code, i.e when you generate the report.

What you would usually be doing is populating a parameter map or maps with different settings for your report. I use parameters if i have a summary page or a cover page (the very first in a report) Something like:

```
parameters.put("authorName", author); //where authorName is a parameter you have created in your JRXML template.
```

Next, you might be using some custom `"variables"` or you might be using variables provided from JasperReports. Some of those useful variables are: PAGE_COUNT and PAGE_NUMBER. They keep track of... report page counts and page numbers. Of course you can have custom variables.

Fields are used where data changes frequently. They are quite similar to parameters but with each iteration the data might change. Like, a field might be a list of `germanCar`  objects for one iteration and a list of `japaneseCar` object for the next. I would use a field to hold the list of `Car` objects that might change.

Bottom line is parameters and fields are quite similar, but fields are populated from the `JasperReportDataSource` (so they can change frequently as you are populating that datasource), while parameters you would use for cover pages or custom JR settings WHILE generating the report itself. They could be quite confusing.

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Thank you for the great answers, One more question is for data to show up on a list, does it have to be in the fields, or say , in Java type, parameters are primitive types and fields are for collections?

Comment: Usually a parameter will hold an object with a value, like a String or a primitive type. Fields might hold a collection of beans, objects etc...

Comment: Can fields be variable in amount ? Or should they be only static ? I mean could a report have specific amount of fields depending on the data provided to the report ?

Comment: A field could be a List object. Then, however many elements you have in your List (passed from your application).

Answer (score 31):

**Parameters** are simple input to JasperReports. You have to define parameters in the JasperReport before using them. You can display the value of the variable, you can use it as part of boolean expressions and you can even pass it to subreports. This can be an input to SQL query.

**Fields** are simple variable definitions. You can think of these as instance variables of the datasource object thats passed in to the report or they can be key names if the datasource is a Map. If you configure JasperReport to create the dataset based on SQL, then Fields are the column names of the ResultSet. You will use Fields to display the resultset of an executed SQL query.

**Variables** are another kind of variables that live within Jasper Report, they are not inputs. They are used to calculate sum or average of certain Field (defined above). You can perform many other predefined calculation functions on the Fields using Variables.

Comment: Thank you. All the samples I saw is pass parameters or results of datasource as fields into a Jasper Report, but how about Java class instance? Is that OK if create a Report Class which holds bunch of parameters and two lists of fields, is it better to pass the whole instance or separate elements to the report ? Which is better? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think creating Report class would be a better approach. Because Report class can abstract the representation of the your Report and it can act as datamodel for report.

Comment: Can fields be variable in amount ? Or should they be only static ? I mean could a report have specific amount of fields depending on the data provided to the report ?

Answer (score 2):

Typically,

`Parameters` are object references that you pass into the report-filling operations. Ideally, someone should take responsibility to pass `parameters` during the report generation process. This responsibility can be delegated to the parent application who is asking `JasperReport` to generate the report or it can be prompted to the user using the `isForPrompting` flag.

`Fields` on the other are place holders for any output returned by the data source.

Let us say we are trying to execute the following `SQL` and show `EMPLOYEE_NAME` and `EMPLOYEE_ID` on the report:

`SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEENAME, EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMPLOYEEID FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'SALES';`

We would want to pass the `DEPARTMENT_NAME` into the query. Hence, we can achieve this in Jasper using a `Parameter`.

The query will now return `EMPLOYEENAME` and `EMPLOYEEID`. We would want someone to hold this value so that we can reference to it. Hence, we can now create two `Fields`: `EmployeeName` and `EmployeeId` to do that.

`Variables` in Jasper are very analogous to variables in any programming language. They are typically used to evaluate report expressions and hold values within them.

Answer (score 0):

**Parameters** are data input that belongs to the whole report. They do not belong to a record/item of the datasource. This can be an input parameter to SQL query.

**Fields** represent attributes/properties of a record/item of the datasource. They are always connected to a datasource. If you use

- database datasource, then JR Fields are the column names of the ResultSet.
- datasource to pass list of items (Java Bean), then JR Fields are the Java class field names.
- datasource to pass list of Map instances, then JR Fields are keys of the Map.

**Variables** actually are named expressions, nothing else.

In JR there are predefined variables like `PAGE_NUMBER`, `REPORT_COUNT`, and others.

You can also define a custom complicated expression, that you want to share and reuse in different parts of the report. To refer to those expressions by name, you use JR Variables - abstractions, that store a mapping between name and the expression.