# Parameter vs field

Tags: java, performance

I'm creating an abstract class with an abstract method `example(boolean b, String s)` that takes 2 parameters.

I want to create some methods for use inside that abstract method, but I need them to use those same parameters. So instead of constantly using `foo(b,s)`, it would be nicer to just use `foo()`.

I thought I could somehow store them in the class. However, my method is potentially spammed so it must not be slower.

```
public abstract class Example {

    public abstract void example(boolean b, String s);

    public void foo() {
        // This method needs the parameters from the above method.
    }

}
```

Possible solution:

```
public abstract class Example {

    protected boolean b;
    protected String s;

    public abstract void example();

    public void foo() {
        // This method can now use 'b' and 's'
    }

    public void run(boolean b, String s) {
        this.b = b;
        this.s = s;
        example();
    }

}
```

If I use these parameters like in the last example above, will it make the process any slower?

Will it cause problems if a thread wants to use this method while another is not finished yet?

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041137/what-is-the-difference-between-variable-parameter-and-field-in-jaspersoft-irepo) stack overflow question for the answer.

Comment: *"but I need them to use those same parameters"* Why need it to be the same and not something the implementation can decide? Are these limitations really necessary?

Comment: If you have just two parameters, I'd say to just suck up the extra few chars of typing. If you had, say, ten parameters, or lots of parameters of the same type where you might accidentally reverse their order, I'd say create a POJO which allows you to pass all of the parameters in one reference.

Comment: One other reason not to use fields is that you can't control what an implementation of `example` will do to the values of `b` and `s`: you can't prevent it from overwriting them to different values, for instance. As such, you can't know for certain what their values are when you execute `foo()`.

Comment: I recommend going one step back: try to explain why you think you need such a solution. You see, if you want to have objects to work on some "fixed" b and s; why don't you create a class with a constructor that takes b and s; and all the methods within that class can then use it? That also allows you to check for null input for example. In other words: people are explaining you a better way to solve the problem you described; but I am wondering: what is the "real" problem you try to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some methods which you want implementations of `example()` to use, and they need invocation-specific values of `b` and `s`, you can put those methods in an inner class:

```
class Example {
  final class Inner {
    final boolean b;
    final String s;

    Inner(boolean b, String s) {
      this.b = b; this.s = s;
    }

    void foo() {
      // This can use the values of b and s passed to run().
    }
  }

  public abstract void example(Inner inner);

  public void run(boolean b, String s) {
    example(new Inner(b, s));
  }
}
```

This is thread safe (with respect to `b` and `s`) because you're not storing the values in shared mutable fields.

Answer (score 3):

Before dealing with speed, let's deal with correctness:

> Will it cause problems if a thread wants to use this method while another is not finished yet?

Assuming that both threads share the same object, the answer is "yes".

However, if you can make it so that each thread uses its own instance of your class, the answer would be "no", because re-assignments from other threads is possible only on shared objects.

> If I use these parameters like in the last example above, will it make the process any slower?

Any speed difference between the two implementations would be minimal, falling into category of premature micro-optimizations. If saving parameters on the object makes sense from readability perspective, and if it does not create concurrency issues, do it; otherwise, keep using parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it cause problems if a thread wants to use this method while
>   another is not finished yet?

Yes its a issue when more than two threads executing the same method and it will be race condition. Ideally you should not have any state in service class as you will run into issues in case of multiple threads

In terms of performance it wont have any impact

You should pass it as method parameters. If not possible due to some issue you can think of putting it in [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> If I use these parameters like in the last example above, will it make the process any slower?

Yes, anything executing within the code takes time. Setting the variables will take a nanosecond or two to execute; although this time increase it insignificant and not worth even considering.

> Will it cause problems if a thread wants to use this method while another is not finished yet?

Depends.

Yes:

- Do both threads share the object?
- Do both modify the state of the object?
- Do both threads concurrently access the object?

No:

- Will the object be immutable.
- Will the object be `synchronized`

If the object is used by both threads the way it is now, you will most likely occur problems.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a class `Execution` that acts as an overlay to the parameters and also contains the methods that require those.

```
public class Execution {
    public final boolean b;
    public final String s;

    Execution(boolean b, String s) {
        this.b = b;
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void foo(); // Uses 'b' and 's'

}
```

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class Example {

    public abstract void example(Execution e);

    public final void run(boolean b, String s) {
        example(new Execution(b, s);
    }

}
```

Implementation:

```
public class ExampleExample extends Example {
    @Override
    public void foo(Execution e) {
        /*
         * Do whatever you want because 
         * you have 'b', 's' and 'foo()'
         * and whatever methods 
         * added to 'Execution'
         *
         */
    }
}
```

I don't know how it will affect the performance, doing it this way. But it solved the dilemma.

Thanks for all your suggestions!